How to continue running code and still get input from user?
How to continue running code and still get input from user so you can select items from typing while in the terminal as code is being ran.
I tried this code:
itemA = False
itemB = False
itemC = False

while True:
    input = input("input example")

    if input == "a":
        # execute a's code
    # execute code

This only executes the code under input() after input() is ran, and asks the input again.
How can I make this run the code under input without stopping for every input()?

Have you tried, moving the code above the input?  Can you be more specific?

Still the same thing. I want the code to execute forever but also be able to ask me the input without having it stop in-between each time. Try executing the code yourself in the terminal and you'll see. Edit: Putting the code above the input just asks the input() after the code is executed. Still doesn't let it execute 'freely'.

You can use the threading package to do this.  This allows you to basically have 2 while loops running at the same time.  In your case, one for input and one for other code.  Here is some code that will do this.
itemA = False
itemB = False
itemC = False
import threading

def execute_code():
    while True:
        # execute code (not waiting for input)
        print("hi")
        continue
threading.Thread(target=execute_code).start()

while True:
    input("input example")
    # execute code (waiting for input)


Thank you! It worked well and I'm using it for a little menu in the terminal so it can execute code associated with different options while still checking for input. Helped a ton.
